# A name for the appendage "s" in plurals, & the possessive, attributive, genitive, ownership

Tags: grammar, terminology

It could be oversight, under-learning or such but on and off I remember that I never learned what to call the game-changer "-s" that comes in to distinguish plurals from singulars. "Plural -s" is all that I learned and use.

Of as much significance is the "-s" that the apostrophe brings with it in the forms of words variously described as possessive, attributive, genitive or ownership. I've been referring to it as the respective "-s," i.e., "possessive -s," etc.

Would have saved a lot of breath if these two applications of the "s" had a name in grammar. Hopefully at least one of them does.

Comment: you mean a collective name?

Comment: Given their different applications and usages I doubt there is a single name to refer to the "s". But you never know.

Comment: Better still, individual names for each. Not the "descriptions" that I mentioned already.

Comment: well, what's wrong with the genitive s, plural s, possessive s etc?

Comment: Someone called one of them a "pluralizer" but still we need to distinguish the "pluralizer s" from the other "pluralizers (esp. of foreign words)."

Comment: Yes, pluralizer is a generic term: *a suffix, prefix, inflection, or auxiliary word which forms a plural.*  Would "plural s" fit? ***Plural vs. Possessive ‘S’*** https://umanitoba.ca/student/academiclearning/media/Plural_vs_Possessive_S_NEW.pdf

Comment: This is the same as the *-s* singularizer for verbs. All three follow the same rules.

Comment: @tchrist +1 for *singularizer* anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The combined term would be **[enclitic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/enclitic)**, but that's hardly more helpful than calling it "**the suffix s**".

Since you need to specify what it's being used for, **plural -s** and **possessive -'s**<sup>¹</sup> are the standard ways to talk about them.

<sub><sup>¹</sup>...or some variant: there's no standardization for dealing with words as words across all English users</sub>

Comment: [ibid.] "An example of differing analyses by different linguists is the discussion of the possessive ('s) in English, some linguists treating it as an affix, while others treat it as a special clitic."

Comment: Btw, you don't need an apostrophe in **possessive -s** it goes *with* the apostrophe.

Comment: @Kris You're wrong but, in your opinion, sure. **Like I said**, there are many ways you could write that and, as long as your convention stays consistent within a document, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Similarly, as the source explains, moving it from one category to another is a side effect of some people trying to make their jargon definition of enclitic more restrictive than what it actually usually means. In any case, it's a **suffix** as well but I'd assume you already knew that and were asking about the *other*, more esoteric term for suffixed morphemes.

Answer (score 1):

I would call the possessive one the [Saxon Genitive](https://www.eamus.it/grammar/saxon-genitive.htm) (this is what it is called in Italian) and this nicely covers both the cases, when it is **'s** and when it is just **'**:

> Saxon Genitive - Possessive of Nouns
>
> Possession is often indicated in English by adding 's or ' at the end of the noun indicating the possessor.

Or just "the possessive".

Comment: +1. I am aware of the term "Saxon Genitive." What troubles me though, is that (1) the above definition is the converse of what we are looking for; and worse, (2) the qualifier *often*, where we would like *exclusively*.

Answer (score 0):

The game-changer s is a form of *declension* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declension)

You can think of it this way: verbs have **conjugation**, nouns have **declension**

But lly is right: you can simply refer to them as "plural s" and "possessive s". Perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Of course, it is a form of declension, that's not its distinctive name.